# Entity Framework Validation confusion - maximum string length of '128'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I'm faced with a confusing problem where in my Edit or Create action result methods, EF4 will throw a DbEntityValidationException with the inner message stating:

> The field Body must be a string or
>   array type with a maximum length of
>   '128'.

The model in question looks like this:

```
[Table("tblArticles")]
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Title must be included")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Start Date must be specified")]
    [Display(Name="Start Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="dd-mm-yyyy")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "End Date must be specified")]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleImage> Images { get; set; }
}
```

The "Body" field in the actual database is of type Text, so there's no obvious limit there.  The data that I'm trying to post is this:

> ```
> <p>
> This is an example to confirm that new articles are looking right.</p>
> <p>
> <img alt="" src="http://www.google.co.nz/logos/2011/houdini11-sr.jpg"
> style="width: 160px; height: 56px; float: left;" /></p>
> ```

An example of the Edit method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Article article)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            articleRepository.Update(article);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbevEx)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(dbevEx);
            ModelState.AddModelError("FORM", dbevEx);
            return View("Edit", article);
        }
        // Other exception handling happens...
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And finally, the method that actually does the grunt work is:

```
public void Update(T Entity)
{
    dbset.Attach(Entity);
    db.Entry(Entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    db.Commit();
}
```

I can't see anything in code or in the database that might be causing the problem, so where else should I look?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Default length of string field in code first is 128. If you are using EF validation it will throw exception. You can extend the size by using:

```
[StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

This post became somehow popular so I'm adding second approach which also works:

```
[MaxLength]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

`StringLengthAttribute` is from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly and `MaxLengthAttribute` is from EntityFramework assembly (EF 4.1).

Comment: Magic. That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me, but in our case it was a problem on some deployments and not others. Turns out a slightly different version of the EF 4.1 dll was deployed.

Comment: Or with fluentconfig: 
   Property(a => a.Body).IsMaxLength();

Answer (score 2):

If you get this error using a Model First approach, check the EF Model: it may be simply that a property on the Entity you're updating has the `Max Length` attribute set.

Answer (score 2):

For Entity Framework 4.3.1, 5.0.0 and 6.2.0, you can use `IsMaxLength()`.

```
Property(m => m.Body ).IsRequired().IsMaxLength();
```

> Configures the column to allow the maximum length supported by the database provider.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringcolumnconfiguration.ismaxlength?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: Could you please fax me this info ;)

Comment: @Gert Arnold I suppose you are implying those versions of EF are old? They might be old but are still being used in some places.

Comment: Sure, I know, the info is useful. Just joking.

Comment: @Gert Arnold no problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

May be you have used

```
Property(m => m.Body ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
```

On your dbcontext class in  OnModelCreating.
So change as per your length

Answer (score 0):

For me, `[MaxLength]` didn't work. I have added below statement to the context.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourModel>().Property(e => e.YourColumn).HasMaxLength(4000);
```

I have not tried exceeding "**4000**" limit but I think it can be extended further. You don't have to keep it **128** as the error showed by compiler.