# Entity Framework 4.1 code first approach: how to define length of properties

Tags: mapping, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

As the title implies:

how is it possible to tell Entity Framework 4.1 in code first approach, that i do want some properties (in particular of type string) to have a length of 256, or nvarchar(max), or...

So if this is for example my model

```
public class Book{
   public string Title { get; set; } //should be 256 chars
   public string Description {get;set} //should be nvarchar(max)
}
```

how could it be defined?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Validation confusion - maximum string length of '128'.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414611/entity-framework-validation-confusion-maximum-string-length-of-128)

Comment: @Ladislav yes it's almost a duplicate,but slightly different! I figured out how: simply use a DataAnnotation for example [StringLength(1000)]  or    [MaxLength]

Answer (score 45):

In EF4.1 RTW default length is nvarchar(max) for SQL Server and nvarchar(4000) for SQL CE. To change the length use either `StringLength` or `MaxLength` annotations or fluent mapping `HasMaxLength`:

```
[StringLength(256)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Or

```
[MaxLength(256)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .Property(p => p.Title)
            .HasMaxLength(256);
```

Comment: hmm! could you please explain why SQL Server 2008 R2 creates by default nvarchar(128) for any string property (and not nvarchar(max) as you say)?

Comment: Because you are using RC and not the latest final RTW version.

Comment: `[StringLength]` only used for validation purposes not as database constraints.

Comment: @Jalal - Can you elaborate on that comment?

Comment: EF6rc1 "code first" generated migration nvarchar max->256 even with stringlength attribute.

Comment: @Jalal @Pasi Savolainen I added `[StringLength(50)]` to a property. Using EF6 RC1 and it put this in my migration: `AlterColumn("dbo.Properties", "OrganisationsReference", c => c.String(maxLength: 50));`

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I want to make a zip code column, that must be 5 chars, no less no more, I want it to be `char(5)` on the DB. How do I do this?

Comment: Can we use both MaxLength and StringLength at the same time? Or will there be a conflict?

Answer (score 3):

As is stated in my comment, it's simple.
Just use `[StringLength(1000)]` or `[MaxLength]` from `DataAnnotation`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way
If you want a Maximum string length

```
[StringLength(Int32.MaxValue)]
```

Or

```
[MaxLength]
```

Or

```
Property(m => m.Title ).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(128);
```

Or

```
[MaxLength(256)]
```