# Any default Entity Framework validation with ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414611/entity-framework-validation-confusion-maximum-string-length-of-128) states that if Entity Framework and code first is used, some default validation is performed.  I am using Entity Framework database-first and would like to use MVC 3 unobtrusive javascript validation.  Is there some default validation that will be performed, such as client-side checking for numbers when the database column is INTEGER, or client-side checking of string length against VARCHAR column lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no client side check unless you add the jQuery.

There are some default checking: DateTime field is always required. I don't have a complete list though.

For code first, you have detailed data annotation already in place, which specifies each field in the database. This annotation will enable a lot of default validation.

However, if it is database first, all you get from the EF is a group of partial classes (corresponding to the tables) with no annotation. The data annotation is usually added in a separate metadata file. Without this extra annotation, no default validation is there. EF simply hands the task of annotation to the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

[check this out](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript) for exactly what you are looking for. You might have to install [Nuget](http://nuget.org/) and get some Asp.Net MVC 3 scaffolding to help you with the templates for these default validation you want. Good luck!

Hanlet