# The field Pdf must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '4000'

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm struggling, trying to save a byte array to my database, using EF (code first), MVC.NET.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
myObjectToSave.Pdf = bytes;
```

The message I get is

> The field Pdf must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '4000'.

The PDF is 20kb!

Research on SO shows a few things about strings, but in my case, my object is

```
public byte[] Pdf {get; set;}
```

I am already using an array!

I am using SQL CE but I don't understand what to do to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the EF Model it should be simply that a property on the Entity you're updating has the Max Length attribute

[same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414611/entity-framework-validation-confusion-maximum-string-length-of-128)

MaxLength attribute : [check here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/maxlength-minlength-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

make sure that field set to varbinary(max) in sql