# The field Password must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '30'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and keep getting the error when trying to save password of more than 30 characters.

`The field Password must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '30'`

I am not sure where this setting is defined in code. The password field length in the database is 100.
I also opened .edmx file and changed max length of password field to 100 but still, I am getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414611/entity-framework-validation-confusion-maximum-string-length-of-128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the length of your string, then your DbContext will assume default lengths.

You can specify the maximum length of strings using Attributes in your classes, or using fluent API. The nice thing about the latter method is that you can use your classes for different databases with different string lengths, precision of decimals, etc. Besides your code looks clearer.

```
class LogInData
{
     ...
     public string Password {get; set;}
}

class MyDbcontext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<LoginData> LoginDatas{get; set;}

    protected override OnModelCreating(...)
    {
        // the rows in the table with LoginData, have a property Password
        // specify the length of this property
        modelBuilder.Entity<LoginData>()
           .Property(loginData => loginData.Password)
           .HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```